# trouble using SSL certificate from Third Party

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate

I am developing a web service that communicates with a third parties web service.  the third party require that I use a SSL certificate with all communication to their system.

In my application I am loading the certificate from a file, "certificate.p12" for example, using the following code:

```
Cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath, certPWD);
```

I then add it to my web request as follows:

```
webRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(Cert);
```

On my development machine this works perfectly, however, on the test server (which is housed externally in a data centre), I simply cannot get it to work.

I've also tried putting the certificate into the certificate store in various locations, current user and local machine, and loaded it from there instead in the code.  Same problem.

Using the current version the application stops as it loads the file... I have debugging information before and after that line and it doesn't get past it but also doesn't throw any error.

I'm very confused... any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

**Update**:  though I'm not 100% certain, I'm pretty sure I am getting an "object not set to an instance of a reference" error on this line

```
Cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath, certPWD);
```

**Update 2**:

"Maybe the test machine is missing the certificate's root chain?"  - I think this is the problem.  Just asked another guy in the office and the certificate  was issued BY the third party and not an existing trusted source.  On my local machine this doesn't seem to be a problem but I assume there is a higher level of security stopping this on the server... now looking at several options,

1. can I bypass this security check for JUST this certificate as we
   know it to be trusted,
2. can I get the root certificates from the
   third party and
3. can I create the root certificates for the third
   party.

Comment: The code just hangs on that line?
If you change the Exception Settings in Visual Studio to break on both handled and unhandled exception, do you still don't see any exception at that line?

Comment: it doesn't so much hang... it breaks out of the function at that point and continues from there but there is no reason for it that I can see... and if I change the exception settings would that work on the published version on the server?  as I can't debug it there properly, only through manually added reporting... and it works on my local machine so it wouldn't catch anything there.

Comment: If you can't install the remote debugger the exception settings won't do any good.

Comment: That's what I thought... sadly I can't install it on the server... well I probably could but I couldn't access it from Visual Studio on my local machine as there is not direct access.

Answer (score 0):

Try contacting the IT support of the data center and make sure that the identity used to run the process that hosts the application has the required permissions to access the certificates store.

Comment: I'm not using the certificates store.  I have the certificate as a .p12 file and I'm opening that.

Comment: Just for testing, drop a simple text file to the same folder as the `p12` file and try to open it for reading with `File.Open(path, FileMode.Open)`. Maybe it's a file system access issue.

Comment: Sadly this too is not the answer... I wondered it myself so I added a new web method that did as you said, read a text file in the same directory but it read it perfectly.

Comment: Another 2 options to investigate:
- Maybe the p12 certificate host name is bound to a specific machine (your dev machine) and it can't be used by the test server?
- Maybe the test machine is missing the certificate's root chain?